# Apache proxypass using a variable URL with interpolate

Tags: apache, configuration, localhost, proxypass, interpolation

I'm trying to set up an Apache server for test purposes. The goal is to simulate a load balancer. The part we're trying to simulate is simply accepting a clients secure httprequest and pass it on (via unsecure HTTP) to the correct server using `ProxyPass`. This all works 100%.

The problem is this: I want to use this "load balancer" for several development environments. To be able to test the server-side of the applications, I want `ProxyPass` to use a variable URL to pass to, being the client’s IP. This will require using a variable URL in the `ProxyPass` rule. I’ve found the variable `REMOTE_ADDR`, but I cannot seem to use this in the `ProxyPass` rule. I first tried the syntax that the Apache website told me to use, but that didn’t work (getting a DNS lookup failure for `http://REMOTE_ADDR/foobar/`). I know I have to do something with `Interpolate`, but I cannot seem to figure out what exactly that would be.

This line does what it should do, so the server works great:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:81/
```

These are the rules I've tried (using the variable) which failed.

```
ProxyPass / http://${REMOTE_ADDR}:81/
Error: [client 127.0.0.1] proxy: DNS lookup failure for: ${remote_addr} returned by /
```

```
ProxyPass / https://%{REMOTE_ADDR}s/
Error: [client 127.0.0.1] proxy: DNS lookup failure for: %{remote_addr}s returned by /
```

```
ProxyPassInterpolateEnv On
...
ProxyPass / http://${REMOTE_ADDR}:81/ interpolate
Error: [client 127.0.0.1] error parsing URL //:81: Invalid host/port
```

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace Proxypass instructions by mod_rewrite rules with the [P] code, P means proxy.

Mod_rewrite will let you do more specific things.

Comment: That would mean something like: RewriteRule ^/ http://%{REMOTE_ADDR}:81/ am i correct?

Comment: yes, maybe, with a [P], but my brain isn't a mod_rewrite engine I cannot be sure :-)

Comment: You can only `ProxyPass` this way, but you cannot `ProxyPassReverse`

Answer (score 15):

For the interpolate case, it's supposed to be like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower

#This sets the variable to env:
RewriteRule ^ - [E=SERVER_NAME:${lowercase:%{SERVER_NAME}}]

#Now interpolate makes variables available for proxypass & proxypassreverse:
ProxyPassInterpolateEnv On
ProxyPass / ajp://${SERVER_NAME}:8009/ interpolate
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://${SERVER_NAME}:8009/ interpolate
```

After searching all night on the Internet, I couldn't find any clear cases like this or any answers. I finally figured it out, though.

Comment: I had tried just about everything, and along the way I dropped the "interpolate" keyword. It works perfectly now. Thank you.

Comment: something seems to have changed in the way apache does this - it now doesnt like the rewritemap line, and the variable doesnt seem to get set