# How to use environment variable from mod_rewrite for interpolate proxypass in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf, mod-proxy

I'm using apache 2.4 and trying to use environment variable inside conf file for proxy pass. There's a thread [[Apache proxypass using a variable URL with interpolate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583235/apache-proxypass-using-a-variable-url-with-interpolate) ]talking about this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower

#This sets the variable to env:
RewriteRule ^ - [E=SERVER_NAME:${lowercase:%{SERVER_NAME}}]

#Now interpolate makes variables available for proxypass & proxypassreverse:
ProxyPassInterpolateEnv On
ProxyPass / ajp://${SERVER_NAME}:8009/ interpolate
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://${SERVER_NAME}:8009/ interpolate
```

But when I tried this myself, I get a "AH00111: Config variable ${SERVER_NAME} is not defined" error. Which means Apache2.4 treats the ${SERVER_NAME} as config variable, rather than environment variable.

I also tried using the mod_rewrite sytax for the variable, like this,

```
ProxyPass / ajp://%{ENV:SERVER_NAME}:8009/ interpolate
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://%{ENV:SERVER_NAME}:8009/ interpolate
```

But %{ENV:SERVER_NAME} was treated as plaintext string, and created an error since it's not a valid URL pass.

Config variables are defined with "Define" block at server launch. What I want is to have the SERVER_NAME changing at runtime using mod_rewrite.
I can't use the mod_rewrite [P] argument, since I need to have the ProxyPassReverse block working with variable as well. mod_rewrite can't deal with rewriting the response, and therefore can't mimic the function of ProxyPassReverse.

Any ideas on how to use environment variable in interpolate proxypass conf directives?

Answer (score 4):

It turns out Apache will still load and work fine, even with the warnings, using this syntax:

`ProxyPassReverse / ajp://${SERVER_NAME}:8009/ interpolate`

This issue was identified in [this mailing list thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-dev/201309.mbox/%3CCAKUrXK7pXPP4EPSYSqpsA=YH1t_JoCnsfMo0Ubg+1FWtRVscoA@mail.gmail.com%3E).  The discussion is about another issue, but they mention this problem and discuss the idea of adding a second interpolation syntax to ProxyPass, etc.  However, I have not found a bug report, and it seems as of Apache 2.4.10, the [mod_proxy code](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/2.4.10/modules/proxy/mod_proxy.c#L542) still supports only the `${varname}` syntax, which conflicts with the overall httpd.conf interpolation.

I haven't found a way to disable those specific warnings, but if you are willing to live with the warnings, Apache should still work for you.

One caveat is that if there is a system environment variable present with the same name when Apache is loading, it will overwrite the value you are trying to interpolate at runtime.

Comment: also very important, it seems setting the environment vars within the location block doesnt work, you need to put it in the virtualhost block

Comment: this ("the mod_proxy code still supports only the ${varname} syntax, which conflicts with the overall httpd.conf interpolation") is still true in 2023 with httpd 2.4.57